# Conditionally load javascript using modernizr

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, parallax, modernizr

I am building a parallax site and I want to turn off the parallax scrolling effect on small viewports (I want to turn off parallax script for viewports below 460px)

I have done some simple fallback css fixes using Modernizr, but can't figure out how to target this perimeter then load in the relevant js files.

I am using scrollr.js for the parallax effect.

http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, it might be more advantageous to use an actual JavaScript loader, especially since Modernizr is all about feature detection for HTML5 and CSS3, and I believe has no native support for JavaScript whatsoever. When that was needed, it was handled by the now deprecated YepNope (see below).

Some potential scripts for your problem are [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/), [LABjs](http://labjs.com/), or [YepNope](http://yepnopejs.com/) **[Deprecated]**.

There are several other posibilities, such as [Head.js](http://headjs.com/), but this is basically a full toolbox, which has features of Modernizr, jQuery, and several other libraries rolled into one. However, for what you want to do, it might be a bit too bulky. There is also [LazyLoad](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/), which is unmaintained, but also should be able to give you the functionality you need.

Further Reading:

[Quora Answer](http://qr.ae/6VG0c)

[ScriptJunkie Article (Same Author as Quora Answer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh227261.aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much @Brandon, what a helpful response. I had a scan through the documentation for scrollr and they had a solution out of the box for my issue. 

However I have struggled with conditionally loading JavaScript in the past and these suggestions look awesome, I will do some of that further reading you suggested :)

Comment: Glad to hear it @RyanCampbell :) I hope that this helps you out lots in the future!

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't need special things, like ordered execution or a callback as soon as the script is loaded and executed, it is quite easy:

```
function loadJS(u){var r=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],s = document.createElement("script");s.src = u;r.parentNode.insertBefore(s,r);}
```

Usage:

```
if(!Modernizr.feature){
    loadJS('path/to/script.js');
}
```

In case you are using jQuery you can do this + then you also have a callback:

```
if(!Modernizr.feature){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/script.js',
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: true,
        global: false,
        crossDomain: true //good for debugging
    });
}
```

So in 90% of all cases you won't need a special loading script.